# Splice matlab vectors

Tags: matlab

I have two matlab vectors. The first has `N` elements, the other has `k*N`. I know what `k` is, and I want to splice the lists such that each element from the first vector appears before the corresponding `k` elements from the next vector. For example:

```
k = 3
x = [1 5 9]
y = [2 3 4 6 7 8 10 11 12]
```

should be combined to look like this:

```
z = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12]
```

Is there an easy way to do this quickly? My x's and y's are pretty big. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this via some reshaping

```
k = 3
x = [1 5 9]
y = [2 3 4 6 7 8 10 11 12]

%# make a k-by-n array
z = reshape(y,k,[]);

%# catenate with x
z = [x;z];

%# reorder
z = z(:)'
```